# Solution to display a long list of words in a single cell : autogroup / sum in libre office calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have a long list of words (1000+) where each word maps to another list of words (around 100 per word of the first list).

Currently I have it stored in excel (libre office calc, in fact) in the following format :

| First list | Second list |
| --- | --- |
| WordA | wordA1;wordA2;wordA3;(...) |
| WordB | wordB1;wordB2;wordB3;wordB4;(...) |
| (...) | (...) |

If required, I can change the input format to something easier to work with, for example:

| First list | Second list |
| --- | --- |
| WordA | wordA1 |
| WordA | wordA2 |
| WordA | wordA3 |
| (...) | (...) |
| WordB | wordB1 |
| WordB | wordB2 |
| WordB | wordB3 |
| WordB | wordB4 |
| (...) | (...) |

Since the "second list" is composed of 100+ words, it's hard to read in a single cell.
Changing `;` to newlines with wrapping will also be quite unreadable.

What I was thinking of is to collapse each word of "First list" into a single line, that can be expanded to the full list of "Second list" if you click on it.

I think it would also be interesting that the collapsed line shows the sum of words that are in the second list.

So basically, given the table above, I want to end up with the following table

| First list | Second list |
| --- | --- |
| +WordA | 3 |
| +WordB | 4 |
| ... | ... |

and if I click on the '+' of wordA, I end up with:

| list | Second list |
| --- | --- |
| -WordA | 3 |
| WordA | wordA1 |
| WordA | wordA2 |
| WordA | wordA3 |
| +WordB | 4 |
| ... | ... |

I'm quite new to calc / excel. How could I achieve that ?

I am also open to other solutions to display this data in a readable format.

Comment: Maybe start by using text to columns, splitting on the `;`

Comment: Change your table to the second format, then create a pivot table with BOTH lists one and two as row elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right, the second version of the table is much better.

By the way, here is the easiest way to convert the original version into a second table: write the formula

```
=A2&CHAR(9)&SUBSTITUTE(B2;";";CHAR(10)&A2&CHAR(9))
```

in cell C2 and extend it to the end of the data.

[image: Formula]

Now select this column and use command [**Data - Text to Columns**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/00/00000208.html)

[image: Text2Columns]

Move the resulting data to the place of the original table.

To get something similar to an expandable list, use [**Data - Subtotals**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12050100.html).

[image: Group]

You now see the number of words in the second list for each word in the first list, and you can collapse and expand the lists by clicking the icons in the bar to the left of the sheet.

[image: PlusMinus]

Comment: several good tips in here!